# i have and issue with "speech_recognition"

Tags: python, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I was trying some code i watched on a video but when i had to run the program it said the following text: "An error ocurred : module 'speech_recognition' has no attribute 'recognize'" i used python

This is my code:

```
import openai

import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
print ("TEST")
import time 


# Initialize OpenAI API
openai.api_key = "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"
# Initialize the text to speech engine 
engine=pyttsx3.init()


def transcribe_audio_to_test(filename):
    recogizer=sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.AudioFile(filename)as source:
        audio=recogizer.record(source) 
    try:
        return recogizer.recognize_google(audio)
    except:
        print("skipping unkown error")

def generate_response(prompt):
    response= openai.completion.create(
        engine="text-davinci-003",
        prompt=prompt,
        max_tokens=4000,
        n=1,
        stop=None,
        temperature=0.5,
    )
    return response ["Choices"][0]["text"]
def speak_text(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def main():
    while True:
        #Waith for user say "genius"
        print("Say 'Genius' to start recording your question")
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            recognizer=sr.Recognizer()
            audio=recognizer.listen(source)
            try:
                transcription = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
                if transcription.lower()=="genius":
                    #record audio
                    filename ="input.wav"
                    print("Say your question")
                    with sr.Microphone() as source:
                        recognizer=sr.recognize()
                        source.pause_threshold=1
                        audio=recognizer.listen(source,phrase_time_limit=None,timeout=None)
                        with open(filename,"wb")as f:
                            f.write(audio.get_wav_data())
                            
                            
                        
                        
                    #transcript audio to test 
                    text=transcribe_audio_to_test(filename)
                    if text:
                        print(f"yuo said {text}")
                        
                        #Generate the response
                        response = generate_response(text)
                        print(f"chat gpt 3 say {response}")
                            
                        #read resopnse using GPT3
                        speak_text(response)
            except Exception as e:
                
                print("An error ocurred : {}".format(e))
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

i clicked on run on visual studio, start debugging and choosed python but when i tried on saying the word i choosed it said the error of "An error ocurred : module 'speech_recognition' has no attribute 'recognize'"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to *isolate* the problem. When you have figured out *where* the error is occurring, try to create the **smallest possible** code that someone else can still **copy and paste, without adding or changing anything** to reproduce the **exact problem, directly**. Show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) corresponding traceback by copying and pasting, **starting from** the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` **until the end**.

Comment: You probably have the wrong library version, different from the video.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line of code:
`recognizer=sr.recognize()`

It should read:
`recognizer=sr.Recognizer()`